# Any reference material for fetching search results from retail sites?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, search, server-side, backend

If the question hasn't already done so, allow me to flag myself as a relative newcomer to backend programming.

I'm really just wondering if anyone could point me to some literature on how to (for example) scrape the results of a search for "Die Hard" from [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com), and list them on your own page.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only Amazon you're trying to deal with?

At any rate, with Amazon your best bet is to use their API, there's a library which makes it all fairly quick and easy to deal with called [CloudFusion](http://getcloudfusion.com/). Took me about 15 minutes to get usable data out of it when I first used it a few weeks ago and most of that time was spent signing up for Amazon API keys, there's a [good tutorial here](http://www.larsko.org/AmazonSearch) to get you going.

BestBuy also has an API called [ReMix](http://remix.bestbuy.com/) which is apparently decent although I've never used it myself.

If you need to deal with other sites as well I've had good results using [PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but you need to keep an eye on scraping simply beacuse a site redesign will most likely break your parser.